# Illustrator Clipping Mask Error

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, clipping-mask

I was trying to make a logo. I used the pen tool to make an outline of the shape (logo). Now I want to power clip an image inside the shape I created. But it doesn't happen! The dialogue box says: "Can't create clipping mask. The top selected object must be a path, compound shape, a text or a group of all." Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hard to say your not describing what you have.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots? are the objects in the right order? have you searched in the Illustrator manual?

Answer (score 0):

That is the message that you get when the *top* object isn't a vector object that can be used as a clipping mask. Therefor I'm assuming your image is above the path you want to use as a clipping mask. To make sure, select the path and go to **Object → Arrange → Bring to Front**.

You can read more about creating clipping masks in the Illustrator help docs:

- [Illustrator Help / Edit clipping masks](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/clipping-masks.html)